# QGraphicsScene and positioning

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How to put QGraphicsScene's (0,0) to top-left corner of QGraphicsView?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `setCenterOn(0,0)` on the `QGraphicsView`?

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsScene` will be filled in the whole `QGraphicsView` but You have the [`setSceneRect`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) function to choose the `QGraphicsScene` part you want to see in the `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: i tried this method, but still can't get what i want.
i call setSceneRect(0, 0, width, height) and point (0,0) of scene displays at the center(~) of GraphicsView.

now i'm doing something like that:
point = View.mapFromScene(QtCore.QPointF(0,0))
obj.setPos(point.x(), point.y())

Comment: Scene is center in the view when view size is superior than scene size. So you need to manage scene size in function of view size in that case.